# What lets the Square of Opposition fail in Intuitionistic Logic?

Tags: lo.logic

**See moderator's note in the comments.**

I just came across the following. In intuitionistic logic
and classical logic we have the following consequences:

```
∃x¬φ → ¬∀xφ  
∀x¬φ → ¬∃xφ  
¬∃xφ → ∀x¬φ
```

But the following consequence is only generally valid
in classical logic but not in intuitionistic logic:

```
¬∀xφ → ∃x¬φ                         (Q)
```

Are there intermediate logics where the last consequence
doesn't fail? I mean a logic where φ v ¬φ doesn't hold
in general but (Q) does.

Bye

Comment: What kind of logics? Obviously, you can just take intuitionistic logic with (Q) as an extra axiom.

Comment: Because, as I already wrote below, the resulting system is conservative over intuitionistic propositional logic: deleting all quantifiers and variables from a proof and turning all predicates into propositional variables results in a valid propositional proof, and specifically, translates (Q) to a tautology $\neg\phi'\to\neg\phi'$. (In other words, (Q) holds in Kripke models with 1-element object domains.)

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. The original question was fine and two users have provided useful information.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I made an error in the original question. I don't want to know whether there is a logic which entails (Q). Its clear that when I add (Q) that it entails (Q). I want to know whether there is an (X), such that (X)+(Q) entails (LEM). If I change the question now all the answers are wrong anyway. So it needs to be deleted.

Comment: @ToddTrimble My question is inspired by http://publish.uwo.ca/~jbell/Epsilon.pdf There fore example the author shows that (X)=(Epsilon) does not entail (LEM). But actually I didn't expect to get answers so quickly. But for example Henry Towsner is only a literature reference. So basically there is only the answer of Andreas Blass which is not relevant to what I need to know, since he doesn't use (Q), something else.

Comment: @ToddTrimble So since there came two quick answers, I am now stuck with a  birth defect. You can see from the logs itself that the question is only 13 hours old. So please delete it.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge You can copy the question and post somewhere else by yourself. I wouldn't mind. But I will not run the question as it was posed. For somebody who knows the matter, it is seen that the question is silly. It has a birth defect.

Comment: I believe in some sense, once you have posted the question, it belongs to the community, not to you.  Evidently, although you think it's silly, other people have found it interesting and useful, and answerers have spent their time writing answers that were also found interesting and useful.  It's against the rules of the site to "vandalize" your own question by editing out the content.

Comment: But it has a birth defect. I cannot be mainted as such. You can copy it and post it somewhere else. But this question definitely doesn't make any sense, as Emil has already pointed out. See the comment of Emil.

Comment: The original poster wanted this question deleted, but we have decided to prevent this. As a general principle, once others have invested effort in giving detailed answers to a question, we do not think it is acceptable to unilaterally delete (or vandalise) a post. I have rolled back the question text here to match the state in which it was answered, and left the post locked.

Comment: Adding to Scott Morrison's comment, a reasonable way to proceed in such a situation, where the original poster decides that the original post was flawed, is to ask an improved question under a separate post.

Answer (score 9):

As Emil pointed out in a comment, the answer to this question will depend on what else is available in your intuitionistic logic.  If that background logic is strong enough, then (Q) will imply the law of the excluded middle.  Specifically, suppose we're working in a higher-order intuitionistic logic (also called intuitionistic type theory) such as arises as the internal logic of topoi, and suppose we adjoin (Q) as a general principle, i.e., with arbitrary formulas $\phi$ and with the variable $x$ ranging over an arbitrary type.  Then we get classical logic, in the form $(\neg\neg\alpha)\to\alpha$ (which is known to imply the law of the excluded middle) as follows.

Given $\alpha$, let $A=\{x\in1:\alpha\}$.  That is, $A$ is the subset of the singleton 1 that contains the unique element of 1 iff $\alpha$ is true.  Then, for any formula $\phi$, we have that $(\exists x\in A)\,\phi$ is equivalent to $\alpha\land\phi$ and that $(\forall x\in A)\,\phi$ is equivalent to $\alpha\to\phi$.  In particular, if we apply (Q) with $\bot$ (the always false proposition) in the role of $\phi$ and with the quantifiers ranging over $A$, then the left side of (Q) is equivalent to $\neg(\alpha\to\bot)$ and thus to $\neg\neg\alpha$, while the right side of $Q$ becomes equivalent to $\alpha\land\neg\bot$ and thus to $\alpha$.  So this particular instantiation of (Q) says $(\neg\neg\alpha)\to\alpha$.

Comment: This is interesting. However, what I actually wanted to point out was the opposite: if we adjoin (Q) as a schema to ordinary first-order intuitionistic logic, it does not prove the law of excluded middle, and in fact it’s a conservative extension of intuitionistic propositional logic (as can be seen by striking out all quantifiers).

Comment: Though your argument does not actually use higher-order logic: it only needs closure under quantifier relativization.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek You're quite right that I'm using only a tiny piece of higher-order logic, namely relativizing quantifiers to a subset of a singleton. (Since quantifying over a singleton is vacuous, I'm tempted to call this "subvacuous" quantification.) Also, I wasn't interpreting your comment on the question as saying (or hinting) that (Q) is strong. I mentioned that comment as a reason for my needing to assume something about the background logic.

Comment: To do this without types, you'd need something else to serve as the domain over which the quantified variables range. If you allow a domain that is a subset of a singleton $\{a\}$ and contains $a$ iff $\alpha$, then my argument still works.  (I don't understand the part of your comment about "if $\phi$ is $\alpha\to\bot$" since that's quite different from the $\phi$ that I suggested.)

Comment: Your claim that "(Q) holds trivially for domains that are subsets of a singleton" is true in classical logic, where the only subsets of a singleton are the singleton itself and the empty set, but it is false in intuitionistic logic. Your further claim that "so you won't derive anything from it" is wrong in the intuitionistic context because I derived $(\neg\neg\alpha)\to\alpha$ from it. I don't see the relevance of the rest of your comment, since you apparently insist on applying (Q) to an implication $(A\to\phi)$, whereas my proof applied (Q) to $\bot$.

Comment: That I assumed the availability of relativization was explicit in my answer ("working in higher-order intuitinonistic logic") and in my first comment to Emil Jerabek. Nothing was smuggled in, I relativized both quantifiers correctly, and my deduction of $(\neg\neg\alpha)\to\alpha$ is correct. I don't intend to answer any more of your comments, but I suggest you read what I wrote (and what Emil wrote) rather than imagining what you think we ought to have meant to write.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to delete everything here. Even if it's not what you wanted, your question, Emil's comment, and my answer may be of interest or even of use to others.  So I would prefer that these things remain on the site, perhaps with an addition to the question saying that it's not really what you wanted.  If you start over, then that should be posted as a new question, perhaps with links to and from this one.

Comment: It’s actually not derivable from (Q) (there is a simple finite counter-model), but that’s besides the point, as $\neg(a=b)$ is not a propositional formula. I didn’t mention equality in the translation, but it is supposed to translate to $\top$ (which should be obvious from the semantic interpretation of the translation). See also http://begthequestion.info .

Comment: Bell additionally assumes $\forall x\,(x=a\lor x\ne a)$, which you omitted. For all I know, his paper is correct. The model looks as follows. The underlying Kripke frame is a tree with a root and two leaves. The first-order domains in all three worlds are $\{a,b,c,d\}$; one leaf satisfies $a=c$ and $b=d$, and the other leaf satisfies $a=d$ and $b=c$. One leaf satisfies $p$. After unwinding the definitions, the validity of (Q) in the model boils down to the property that each equivalence class in one leaf intersects each equivalence class in the other leaf.

Comment: @j4nbur53 My post does answer your question, in the negative.  Specifically, it shows that, with an appropriate intuitionistic background logic (a type theory, or just one allowing certain relativizations), one cannot have (Q) without $\phi\lor\neg\phi$. Emil had already answered the question in the case of a very weak background logic (containing only propositional logic).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if there's a system short of classical logic where (Q) holds for all formulas, however the principle
$$\forall x(\phi\vee\neg\phi)\rightarrow(\neg \forall x\neg\phi\rightarrow\exists x\phi)$$
(or sometimes
$$\forall x(\phi\vee\neg\phi)\rightarrow(\neg \neg\exists x\phi\rightarrow\exists x\phi)$$
instead)
is *Markov's principle*, and there's a great deal of work on constructive logics with Markov's principle.